# Rails Service Objects and Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

In my Rails4 app I have created a **Services** folder within my app that contains a `StripeCommunicator.rb` class - this (as the name suggests) takes care of communication with Stripe's Payment Processing service.

**I would like to know** how to trap errors from this class and return them to the controller ready for use in the view.

In my old setup in my model (before using a Service Object) I trapped errors like this:

```
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  errors.add :base, e.message
  false
```

but this approach no longer works and I'm not sure of a suitable solution???

Answer (score 2):

Make the Service objects behave as ActiveModel objects. If you just want the validation and the error behaviour from ActiveRecord objects, you could just use ActiveModel::Validations

```
class ServiceObject
  include ActiveModel::Validations
end
```

And you could happily do

```
errors.add :base, e.message
```

or

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name
```

Refer to this blog for more information about [ActiveModel::Validations](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/)

Comment: and could you just clarify how I would make my service object behave as an ActiveModel - assuming I wanted a little more than Validations?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the page i linked to in my answer? That has all the information about other modules in ActionModel that you could use.

Comment: sorry yes - i used `< ActiveRecord::Base` in the end - bit early there - apologies